# Prepare and setup Raspberry Pi image on a PC (virtual machine)

Tags: windows, java, sd-card, raspberry-pi

I am considering using a Raspberry Pi in a simple project. It should run some small Java (preferably) or Python console application, in its essence a very simple server. I know this will not be a problem for it and what I have to do is just install a Linux distro and add a Java package (which seems a little fiddly but much easier with Java 8).

What I would like to know is could this be done on an image of an SD card using some virtual machine on a Windows PC? Basically I want to set up the OS, install packages and set up my program to run on boot (and probably enable SSH), and only then write that virtual image to an SD card and insert it into the Pi to use it. What programs would I need to accomplish this, and are there some tutorials? Also I will probably use this same image on 2 or 3 Raspberry Pis later.

Comment: What has your research on running an ARM/Linux distro proven?  I am not aware of a solution that would allow that?  You can boot Debian ( same distro that comes with the RPi ) to get an idea how it will work.

Comment: For my requirements any distro could be used and I will probably use the Debian suggested on the Pi Website. Basically the only parts I don't know how to do are: how to run ARM image in a Virtual Machine on a PC and how to save that image after installing software and setting it up in correct format for the PI.

Comment: The only solution to this idea I have seen is [QEMU](http://xecdesign.com/qemu-emulating-raspberry-pi-the-easy-way/).  That being said, in my experience it was buggy and gave you limited storage space (solutions on their page).  I would personally write the Java code on your box and then move it over (scp).  You know, since Java is supposed to be portable.

Comment: I heard of QEMU but haven't used it yet so didn't have a clue that it could be used to emulate Raspberry Pi so if it works that is probably an answer to the first part of the question. I am going to test it right now.

Comment: Second part of the question still remains open on how do you save disk image from QEMU to be compatible with Pi?

Comment: @PSIXO - Depends on what sort of image file QEMU uses.

Comment: I tested QEMU and wasn't able to start it but after that found a prepared directory and it worked, I don't know if I can post links with low reputation but if you need this just google Raspberry pi QEMU windows pack. All in all QUEMU is the right answer to first part of the question but I still don't know are it's images compatible with the Pi and are there some tools that can convert them.

Comment: So, it turns out you can use QEMU the way I wanted since even the  SD card images are compatible. Unfortunately none of the commentators wrote an answer so I cannot accept anything, if @nerdwaller is still following I think your comment is the best as it gave me most info so if you write it in form of an answer I will accept it (please if you can include the link I mentioned above in order to help others who might see this question).

Comment: @PSIXO - Updated.  Thanks for checking back in on that.  Glad that it was helpful to get you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most solid solution that I have seen for this is [QEMU](http://xecdesign.com/qemu-emulating-raspberry-pi-the-easy-way/).  That being said, in my experience it was somewhat buggy and provided little in the way of storage space (*note: there is a solution on their page now, though I cannot vouch for it*).

Personally, I would write the Java code locally (on my normal computer) and move it over - since Java is supposed to be nearly infinitely portable.

Comment: I abandoned Java in favor of a little bit more complex Bash scripts. Although I did get Java to work without a problem. QEMU is the right way to emulate the Pi on windows so this is the correct answer.PS.Yes it is a little bit buggy but nothing critical, even the default networking setup works great.